# ODP Oracle.DataAccess was working with .NETFramework 4.5 but not with .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, odp.net

In my application, i'm connecting to an Oracle DB via ODP. I was using `.NET 4.5` and everything was working fine but then for Windows XP compatibility i changed framework to .NET 4.0 on all the projects on my solution. Application is built on .NET 4.0 succesfully but can not connect to DB via ODP and throws exception:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

I had created a `References` folder in Solution folder(near projects) and adding the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` file as reference from there to the projects those use it. May it be the problem?

Comment: i guess require version is not the same for 4.5 and 4.0?

Comment: Actually i get the dll from ODAC tools installation folder, did not separately download it. I don't think it's a version incompatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main(`winforms`) project of the solution i changed the `platform target` from any CPU to `x86` and now it's working on `.NET 4.0.`